# Meaning of Power Analysis function parameters for SSizeLogisticBin when A/B test in R

Tags: r, statistical-power, ab-test

I did recently an A/B testing course in R from DataCamp and I could not understand the parameter **B** from the following function from the package **powerMediation**

```
SSizeLogisticBin(
  p1 = 0.58,    
  p2 = 0.88,    
  B = 0.5,     # Proportion from the data from the Test Condition (ideally 50%)
  alpha = 0.05,
  power = 0.8  
)
```

My questions are:

- It is the proportion of what? The amount of test data compared to
  control? But isn't it what we want to know in a power analysis? how
  could we know beforehand?
- Or, Is it the proportion between 0s and 1s from the test condition?
  but it ends up being equal p2.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this package, if you check the [code](https://github.com/cran/powerMediation/blob/master/R/powerLogisticsReg.R), it is the probability of X=1. I hope I got the terminology correct for A/B testing, it means the probability of someone clicking / choosing. Most of the time you assume it to be 0.5, but in some situations or cases other than A/B testing, this probability might be different.

Side note: If you check the [citation](http://personal.health.usf.edu/ywu/logistic.pdf) behind this package, it's actually for something else..

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, `B` is the `Pr(x=1)`, which is confusing if it is read in terms of a conversion rate rather than a binary covariate in a logistic regression model. It took a minute to click for me as well. If you are running an A/B test, `x=1` if the customer is exposed to the treatment and `x=0` if the customer is exposed to the baseline. Consider the following model,

$y_i \sim Binomial(n,p_i) \\
logit(p_i) = \alpha + \beta x_i$

If you set `B=0.5`, you are simply stating that the customer is exposed to the treatment at the same frequency as the baseline, so $x_i=1$ half the time. If you set `B=0.25`, then $x_i=1$ 1/4 of the time.

```r
library(powerMediation)

# B = 0.5 
n <- SSizeLogisticBin(
  p1 = 0.58,    
  p2 = 0.88,    
  B = 0.5,     
  alpha = 0.05,
  power = 0.8  
) 

n_treatment <- n_baseline <- n

# B = 0.25
n <- SSizeLogisticBin(
  p1 = 0.58,    
  p2 = 0.88,    
  B = 0.25,     
  alpha = 0.05,
  power = 0.8  
)

n_treatment <- n
n_baseline <- n/0.25
```